Python curve fitting gone wrong
I am trying to fit some data to a theoretical Laser interferometric vibrating speaker system characterization model, and I am running into some problems. Here's the mathematical model:

Here's the code for the scatter plot, and it checks out as a pulse.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

freq = [ 100, 140, 180, 200, 220, 240,
       260, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320,
       340, 360, 400, 440, 480]

omega = [x*2*pi for x in freq]

cycles = [18, 20.5, 23, 27, 26.5, 29,
       26, 22.5, 28, 27.5, 27.5,
       23, 14, 20, 12, 15.5, 13]

current  = [ 1.20, 1.22, 1.24, 1.25, 1.05, 0.91,
      0.61, 0.34, 0.32, 0.25, 0.25, 0.26,
       0.45, 0.78, 0.78, 1.63, 1.90]

x0 = [cycle*633/4 for cycle in cycles]
i0 = [curr*np.sqrt(2) for curr in current]

ampl = [x0/i0 for x0,i0 in zip(x0,i0)]


plt.scatter(omega, ampl, label='data')
plt.title("Amplitude [x₀/i₀] x Frequency [ω]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude of vibration by current amplitude [x₀/i₀]")
plt.xlabel("Angular Frequency [ω]")
plt.show()

But for the curve-fitting, it just does not return the correct shape:
def form(omega, Bl, m, b, k):
    omega = np.array(omega)
    return (Bl/k)/np.sqrt((1 - np.power(omega,2)*(m/k))**2 + np.power(omega,2)*(b/k)**2)

p0 = (1.73, 0.94, 0.10*10**-3, 1.5*10**3)

param, covariance = optimize.curve_fit(form, omega, ampl, p0=p0)

Bl, m, b, k = param

plt.scatter(omega, ampl, label='data')
plt.plot(omega, form(omega, *param), 'b-', label='fit')
plt.show()

With this result:

I've initially tried using a1...a3 parameters instead of Bl/k...b/k, and also using the paper's conclusion for initial parameter estimates, but it's the same overall. Is there something I'm doing clearly wrong?
I attempted to fit some experimental data to a pre-determined model pulse curve, but it returns a straight line. I tried rewriting parameters, passing the data as an array, and using initial guesses, but to no avail.


When the fit is not good, an usually good idea is to normalize the data...  and I mean just a rough, mindless normalization (see the code), also notice that I have not provided a p0 to curve_fit.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

freq = np.array([ 100, 140, 180, 200, 220, 240,
       260, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320,
       340, 360, 400, 440, 480])

omega = freq*2*np.pi
omega_dense = np.linspace(0, 3000, 301)

cycles = np.array([18, 20.5, 23, 27, 26.5, 29,
       26, 22.5, 28, 27.5, 27.5,
       23, 14, 20, 12, 15.5, 13])
current  = np.array([ 1.20, 1.22, 1.24, 1.25, 1.05, 0.91,
      0.61, 0.34, 0.32, 0.25, 0.25, 0.26,
       0.45, 0.78, 0.78, 1.63, 1.90])
x0 = cycles*633/4
i0 = current*np.sqrt(2)
ampl = x0/i0

# model
f = lambda w, a1, a2, a3: a1/np.sqrt((1-w**2*a2)**2+w**2*a3**2)
# fit on normalized data
omega_fac, ampl_fac = 2000, 1500
(a1, a2, a3), cov = curve_fit(f, omega/omega_fac, ampl/ampl_fac)
# undo normalization
a1, a2, a3 = amp_fac*a1, a2/omega_fac**2, a3/omega_fac
# format the parameters for inclusion in label
a1s, a2s, a3s = [fmt(a,4) for a in (a1, a2, a3**2)]
label = r'$\frac{%.2f}{\sqrt{\left(1-%s\omega^2\right)^2+%s\omega^2}}$'%(a1, a2s, a3s)

# plotting
plt.title("Amplitude [x₀/i₀] × Angular velocity [ω]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude of vibration by current amplitude [x₀/i₀]")
plt.xlabel("Angular velocity [ω]")

plt.scatter(omega, ampl, label='data')
plt.plot(omega_dense, f(omega_dense, a1, a2, a3), label=label)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize='xx-large')
plt.grid()
plt.show()

def fmt(v, decimals):
    num = ('%%.%dg'%decimals)%v
    if num[-4:-2] == 'e-':
        n = num[:-4]
        e = '%d'%int(num[-2:])
        return r'\frac{'+n+'}{10^{-'+e+'}}'
    return num


You need a good initial guess (or be prepared to do a lot of trial and error). You can relate parameters m/k and b/k by looking at where the maximum is (differentiate your functional form), whilst Bl/k is the value when omega=0, so your data suggests that will be between 1000 and 2000.
Note that my parameters are Bl/k, m/k and b/k.

Final Parameter Values:
Bl/k, m/k, b/k= 1317.616465117712 2.719980977630381e-07 5.244771826019325e-05

Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

freq = [ 100, 140, 180, 200, 220, 240,
       260, 280, 290, 300, 310, 320,
       340, 360, 400, 440, 480]

omega = [x*2*pi for x in freq]

cycles = [18, 20.5, 23, 27, 26.5, 29,
       26, 22.5, 28, 27.5, 27.5,
       23, 14, 20, 12, 15.5, 13]

current  = [ 1.20, 1.22, 1.24, 1.25, 1.05, 0.91,
      0.61, 0.34, 0.32, 0.25, 0.25, 0.26,
       0.45, 0.78, 0.78, 1.63, 1.90]

x0 = [cycle*633/4 for cycle in cycles]
i0 = [curr*np.sqrt(2) for curr in current]

ampl = [x0/i0 for x0,i0 in zip(x0,i0)]


plt.scatter(omega, ampl, label='data')
plt.title("Amplitude [x0/i0] x Frequency [ω]")
plt.ylabel("Amplitude of vibration by current amplitude [x0/i0]")
plt.xlabel("Angular Frequency [ω]")


def form(omega, Blk, mk, bk ):
    omega = np.array(omega)
    return Blk / np.sqrt( ( 1 - omega ** 2 * mk ) ** 2 + omega ** 2 * bk ** 2 )

p0 = (2e3, 0.25e-6, 1e-4 )
param, covariance = optimize.curve_fit(form, omega, ampl, p0=p0)
Blk, mk, bk = param
print( "Bl/k, m/k, b/k=", *param )

plt.scatter(omega, ampl, label='data')
plt.plot(omega, form(omega, *param), 'b-', label='fit')
plt.show()

